# Using TypeScript, how can you allow undefined props but still enforce a discriminated union?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union

I'm building a component library in React that's written in TypeScript. The components have a particular set of props but they also allow you to add any props you want, such as data attributes and aria tags or anything else you might need. To accomplish this in TypeScript, I am using this:

```
interface LinkProps {
  color?: string;
  icon?: ReactNode;
  ...
  // allow any prop
  [x: string]: unknown;
}
```

The `unknown` allows you to do this:

```
<Link data-anything="something" aria-label="myid">example link</Link>
```

Without the `unknown` prop, TS would throw an error. The problem is that I want to use a discriminated union to require either a `children` prop OR a `text` prop.

```
interface LinkPropsCommon {
  color?: string;
  icon?: ReactNode;
  ...
}

interface LinkPropsChildren extends LinkPropsCommon {
  children: ReactNode;
  text?: never;
}

interface LinkPropsText extends LinkPropsCommon {
  children?: never;
  text: string;
}

type LinkProps = LinksPropsChildren | LinkPropsText;
```

This generally works to enforce either the `children` or `text` prop and throws an error if *both* props are provided.

```
// typescript throws an error
<Link text="example link">example link</Link>
```

However, with the inclusion of `[x: string]: unknown;` in `LinkPropsCommon`...

```
interface LinkPropsCommon {
  color?: string;
  icon?: ReactNode;
  [x: string]: unknown;
}
```

...both props can be used together and no error will be thrown. I'm not sure why.

```
// typescript does not throw an error
<Link text="example link">example link</Link>
```

Is there a way to do this kind of discriminated union while still allowing undefined props to be used?

Comment: If you want to support aria attributes and `data-*` attributes, why not use something like this? https://tsplay.dev/m333km

Comment: @vera. ```[key: `data-${string}`]: string``` is impressive! What's that syntax called?

Comment: @Drenai [Template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html)

Comment: @vera. That's an interesting suggestion but I want to leave it open ended. For instance, someone should be able to use `<Link href="http://example.com">example</Link>` without me defining `href` as a prop. Even that may be too specific of an example. Basically any undocumented props should be spread to the root element, like MUI, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the other property with type **never**.

This works fine for me:

```js
interface LinkPropsCommon {
  color?: string;
  icon?: ReactNode;
}

interface LinkPropsChildren extends LinkPropsCommon {
  children: ReactNode;
}

interface LinkPropsText extends LinkPropsCommon {
  text: string;
}

type LinkProps = LinkPropsChildren | LinkPropsText;

const Link = (props: LinkProps) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}>example link</div>
  );
}

const MyFunction = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link text="example link"></Link>
      <Link>example link</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And also with defining them with type **never**:

```js
interface LinkPropsCommon {
  color?: string;
  icon?: ReactNode;
}

interface LinkPropsChildren extends LinkPropsCommon {
  children: ReactNode;
  text?: never;
}

interface LinkPropsText extends LinkPropsCommon {
  text: string;
  children?: never;
}

type LinkProps = LinkPropsChildren | LinkPropsText;

const Link = (props: LinkProps) => {
  return (
    <div {...props}></div>
  );
}

const MyFunction = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link text="example link"></Link>
      <Link>example link</Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```